# La instancia de ObjectContext se ha desechado y ya no se puede usar para operaciones que requieren una conexión

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando intento mostrar en un `View` una lista de registros de un usuario me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

> La instancia de ObjectContext se ha desechado y ya no se puede usar para operaciones que requieren una conexión.

Debuggeando me dí cuenta de que el error explota en el siguiente código:

```
 public bool tienePermisoConvenio(Permiso permiso, Convenio cnv)
    {
     // En la primera linea arroja el mensaje de error
      var permic= this.Permiso_Usuario_Convenio.FirstOrDefault(puc => puc.Convenio.idConvenio == cnv.idConvenio && puc.idPermiso == permiso.idPermiso);
      return null != permic? permic.estaActivo : false;
       
    }
```

Lo más extraño es que cuando ingreso con otro usuario que posee los mismos registros que el otro todo sale perfectamente.

Estuve leyendo que ese error da porque el `ObjectContext` se cerró antes de terminar la lectura del query, entonces a la linea de arriba le agregué lo siguiente:

```
public bool tienePermisoConvenio(Permiso permiso, Convenio cnv)
    {
        using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
        {
            var permic = db .Permiso_Usuario_Convenio.FirstOrDefault(puc => puc.Convenio.idConvenio == cnv.idConvenio && puc.idPermiso == permiso.idPermiso);
            return null != permic ? permic.estaActivo : false;

        }
                     
    }
```

EL mensaje de error ya no me lo muestra, pero al mostrarme mi registro, tengo unas columna de encendido y apagado y siempre me lo muestra encendido cuando debe estar apagado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora con el usuario que no me da el error de

> La instancia de ObjectContext se ha desechado y ya no se puede usar para operaciones que requieren una conexión.

Me muestra las columnas apagadas y así debería ser.

¿Por qué cuando mi variable `var permic` recibe con `this` la consulta linq me muestra el mensaje de error?, ¿Y por qué cuando utilizo mi cláusula `using` para mi consulta no me muestra el error, pero mis datos los trae encendidos?

La consulta sigue siendo la misma, lo único que cambio es de `this` a mi consulta con mi clausula `using` como pueden ver el codigo de arriba.

Comment: Con el código que incluyes no es suficiente para conocer sobre su estructura. Por ejemplo, no queda claro si creas tu contexto utilizando `new TPConveniosEntities()` porque no está integrado dentro de EF y no lo puedes inyectar en tu clase, o si es un error en tu código.

Comment: que necesita que le proporcione? cuando utilizo el new TPConveniosEntities(), no me da error. y donde coloque la imagen esta siempre encendida y no deberia, en cambio si uso this, aveces me lanza el error y donde coloque la imagen me la trae correctamente